# AndroidManifest.xml change some <intent-filter> location for show other activity (old project to new project )

Tags: android, android-manifest

*this my old project* **how to change this (intent-filter) filter.** for the show other activity

androidManifest.xml

```
            <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity" >
                 <intent-filter>
                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                 </intent-filter>

            </activity>

           <activity
               android:name=".MainActivity"
               android:label="My Food App"
               android:theme="@style/Theme.MyFoodApp.NoActionBar">
      
    </activity>
```

this my new project

```
           <activity
             android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
             android:exported="false" />

           <activity
             android:name=".LoginActivity"
             android:exported="false" />

           <activity
             android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
             android:exported="false" />

           <activity
             android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:exported="true"
             android:label="My Food App"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.MyFoodApp.NoActionBar">
           <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
       </activity>
```

---

**Where to put the  in new project for show other activity**

Comment: just explain more about what you want to do .. it is not clear.

Comment: I make project in  (( navigation drawer activity )) 
and i show  olny  ((  ".WelcomeActivity"  ))   So where do I put the <intent-filter> ?

So I can only see .WelcomeActivity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see WelcomeActivity when you open your project first, you can put Main and Launcher intent filter in WelcomeActivty block like below :

```
           <activity
             android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
             android:exported="false" />

           <activity
             android:name=".LoginActivity"
             android:exported="false" />

           <activity
             android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
             android:exported="false" >
                 <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                 </intent-filter>
           </activity>

           <activity
             android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:exported="true"
             android:label="My Food App"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.MyFoodApp.NoActionBar">
       
           </activity>
```

Comment: thank you for answered but not working. (A red line appears below the android:exported="false" ) He suggests me to do the true not false

Comment: And if I do true then the app goes off